# Return a struct from a Solidity Contract

Tags: solidity, struct

I'm just trying to get confirmation as to whether this is supported within Solidity currently.  Older responses to this question seem to imply this has been added, but I can't find any concrete literature to confirm.

If I have a struct within the contract, can I return it via a getter on the contract?  For example:

```
struct myDetails {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
}

function getName() returns (???) {
    return myName;
}
```

Thx

Marty

Answer (score 4):

It's not currently possible to return a struct to the outside with your *own* function. Nonetheless, it's possible with Solidity's automatically generated getters.

By marking a variable `public` (for example `uint public someNumber`) Solidity will automatically generate a getter (`someContract.someNumber()`). This will indeed work on structs (`Foo public someFoo`) and even arrays and mappings! (`mapping(uint => player) public players`) In the last case, you provide a key to the getter to get the one you want. (`someContract.players(7)`)

One caveat: Nested structs, arrays, and mappings inside of structs are currently not returned by getters. Strings, however, are.

Comment: In `mapping(uint => player) public players`, the value type `player` seems to be a user-defined, i.e. non-primitive type. So I presume it would be some struct or mapping. So if `someContract.players(7)` returns a `player`, does that mean that structs inside of mappings can be returned even though mappings inside of structs cannot (which you mention in the caveat later)?

Comment: Structs can be retrieved through mappings by this method, yes.

Comment: Now it's 2018/1, is it still true that "It's not possible to return a struct to the outside with your own function"? Tried in Remix and seems it doesn't reject the idea of returning a struct completely. However it generates a compilation error which might be related. I asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160495/why-the-struct-is-larger-than-32-bytes

Answer (score 0):

in the official repos there is no indication about allowing a return of the struct type. check https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases

I suggest you to use multiple return for your getName  function.

```
function getName() returns (string,string) {

 string firstName;
 string lastName;
  return (firstName, lastName);
}
```