# returning array of struct in remix

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays, struct

Seems like there are many related questions ex: [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29365/returning-structs-in-new-version-in-solidity), but I still can't believe it is not supported in remix or am I misunderstanding it? seems like it is supported in production.

```
struct Test {
    address receiver;
    string date;
} 

mapping(address => Test[]) public testInfo;

function getTestInfo(address _account) public constant returns (Test[]) {
    return testInfo[_account];
}
```

Is there anyway to execute that code and return an array of `Test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will run however the output won't be decoded. You will see this message in the console:

```
failed to decode output: Error: Unsupported or invalid type: tuple
```

I was going to suggest destructuring and returning two arrays however there is a string in the struct, which is also cannot be returned since string is an array itself. You named it `date` so maybe it can be held in an `uint` field or maybe in a `bytes32` field? If that's the case than you can do:

```
function getTestInfo(address _account) public constant returns (address[], bytes32[]) {
```

I.e., return struct fields in separate arrays and restructure them in your front-end.

Comment: ok so seems like it can be decoded in production environment? and not so sure what you meant by return struct fields in separate arrays. The size is dynamic.

Comment: What are you referring to by 'production environment'? What I mean by destructing is suppose you want to return 10 Tests. You return 10 `address`es and 10 `bytes32`s, let's call them `receivers` and `dates`. Each element in those arrays are set to the respective fields of the `Test` in the original array, e.g. `receivers[0] == Tests[0].receiver` and `dates[0] == Tests[0].date`. You can build a `Tests` array from this structure in the front-end.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried with your way and it worked. But I used bytes32 for dates ex: `2018-01-31` and what it returns is the address `0x323031382d30312d323800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` What can be fixed?

Comment: That's not an address, it's the hex representation of the string '2018-01-31', you can search for ways of converting it. If the formatting doesn't have to preserved, I suggest you use `uint`s for dates.

Comment: Thank you very much. Hopefully I don't need to go through couple of more steps in the future.