# Getter of mapping inside a struct

Tags: remix, mapping, struct, solidity-0.5.x

I wanted to create a getter function to access a mapping nested inside a struct. But the function that I made required me to use the expiremental version (I'm on Remix).

So I used the expiremental version to verify if the code I had done was correct and it was. Here the used code that I simplified as much as I could:

```
pragma solidity  ^0.5.16;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract SupChain{

enum StateType {Created, InTransit, Stored, OutOfComplicance, Completed}

struct Status{
    StateType state;
    address currentCounterparty;
    string test;
}

struct Order{
    uint256 orderID;
    uint256 NumberOfUpdate;
    string test;
    mapping (uint256 => Status) statutes;
}

mapping (uint256 => Order) public orders;

function getStatus(uint256 id, uint256 concernedStatusNumber)           
                   public returns (Status memory status){
    Order storage concernedOrder = orders[id];
    Status memory concernedStatus = concernedOrder.statutes[concernedStatusNumber];
    return concernedStatus;
}
```

Now I would like to be capable to access to the map without using the expiremental version. How do I code such a getter version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From last Solidity Documentation:
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/contracts.html#return-variables

At the end of RETURN-VARIABLES section in the NOTE paragraph:
"You cannot return some types from non-internal functions, notably multi-dimensional dynamic arrays and structs. If you enable the new ABIEncoderV2 feature by adding pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2; to your source file then more types are available, but mapping types are still limited to inside a single contract and you cannot transfer them."

So you can return structs but only for internal calls. See also here:
[solidity-function-to-return-a-data-struct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18064/solidity-function-to-return-a-data-struct)